# Can't scrape an embedded table in html with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the lower half of this site: "https://www.businessregistry.gr/publicity/show/131260660000.html", but it usually returns NA or zero length. I would like to end up with a data frame of several companies, changing the numeric part of the URL. Thanks a lot!

Here's an example of my code:

```
#working as expected
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
aek_page=read_html("https://www.businessregistry.gr/publicity/show/131260660000.html")

#getting zero
aek_page %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  as.character()

#getting empty df
data_df=data.frame(decision_date=html_text(html_nodes(aek_page, "td:nth-child(1)")),
                 decision_body=html_text(html_nodes(aek_page, "td:nth-child(2)")),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```